# Perché si dice "tutti e due" e non "tutti due"?

Tags: conjunctions, phrases

Esiste proprio una ragione  grammaticale dietro questa frase o è solo un modo di dire? E qual è il ruolo della congiunzione "e" in mezzo?

Comment: Anch'io sono veramente incuriosita da questa questione perché in catalano diciamo "tots dos" la cui traduzione letterale sarebbe "tutti due". Sempre ho trovato strano il modo di esprimere questa idea degli italiani.

Comment: Per confronto, in francese si dice *tous les deux* ("tutti i due"). Sarebbe interessante vedere come quest'espressione vari nelle lingue romanze

Comment: Se ne parla qui: http://www.treccani.it/magazine/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/grammatica/grammatica_069.html

Comment: In questa [*Grammatica filosofica della lingua italiana*](https://books.google.es/books?id=QhRgAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA128&lpg=PA128&dq=%22tutti+due%22+%22tutti+e+due%22&source=bl&ots=CF50pj_NP7&sig=U42CmvBNGiX0uHP0vXVgCnhac-Q&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjaipjhwejfAhUUShUIHSYHDBgQ6AEwCXoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22tutti%20due%22%20%22tutti%20e%20due%22&f=false) dell'Ottocento si trovano questi esempi: «1. *Tutti e tre parimente gli amava* B. 2. *Si spogliarono tutte e sette*. B. 3. *Era in pericolo di perdere tutti due i figliuoli*. 4. *Poteva essere, poichè noi eravamo tutti due nati a un tempo*.»

Comment: «F. 5. *Questo è certo ch'ella v'ha in vitato tutti a due*. F. 6. *Tutti a due tirate a un segno*. F.»

Comment: Dopodiché si  può leggere: «L'ordine intero delle espressioni *tutti e due*, *tutti e tre*, ecc; si è *tutti e sono due*, *tutti e sono tre*. Si dice anche *tutti due*, *tutti tre*; *tutti a due*, *tutti a tre*; la prima maniera è la più usata.»

Comment: E poi: «Il Bartoli e l'Amenta non sanno che diavolo ci faccia questa *e* tra il numero e la voce *tutti*; e non ce la vorrebbero; ma in questo caso si vede bene che la voce *tutti* comprende un numero circonscritto; onde viene la conseguenza che si debba definirlo; e questa definizione s'aggiunge alla voce *tutti* per mezzo della congiunzione.»

Comment: «L'idea, dunque, compresa nel primo esempio è: *Gli amava tutti, e voi sapete che e' sono tre*; e a me riesce maniera assai più regolare in tali proposizioni mettere la congiuntiva che no; e per lo contrario mi pare manchi qualche cosa nella espressione *tutti tre*; poichè non si dice *tutti uomini*, *tutte cose*, parlando generalmente; vi si pone l'articolo che addita la cosa determinata; in somma vi vuol sempre una unione tra la voce *tutto* e quella che la determina.»

Comment: «Nello stesso modo, mettendo la preposizione, come ne' due ultimi esempj, la idea è: *tutti, e voi sapete che questo tutti si riduce a voi due*. Così ragionando si solve; e, così solvendo, non sarà mai bisogno che i grammatici vengano a battaglia.» Mi sembra una spiegazione divertente.

Comment: In romeno, nel caso di 2 si può dire solo "amandoi" (che sarebbe "entrambi"); negli altri casi si dice "toti 3", "toti 4" ecc (che sarebbe "tutti 3", tutti 4" ecc). Probabilmente c'entra poco, ma nel francese l'articolo "les" si usa anche il altre situazioni dove non ha corrispondente in italiano, per esempio "les maison les plus belles", che in italiano diventa semplicemente "le case più belle".

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE, @Alex! Quello che spieghi è interessante, ma mi sembra più un commento che una vera risposta. Per questa ragione, il tuo post sarà convertito in un commento.

Answer (score 5):

È una regola grammaticale: ***con i numerali "tutto" è seguito dalla congiunzione "e":***

> tutti e due (o tutt'e due)
>   tutti e sette
>   tutti e dieci

Comment: Non capisco perché la mia risposta corretta sia stata "downvotata". Vedo che in questa piattaforma è molto amato il sito Treccani, posto il link che riporta la regola: http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/quantificatori_(Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano)/

Comment: Treccani: "Quando tutti è seguito da un numerale, si interpone la congiunzione e (tutti e due)."

Comment: Non ho votato, ma la risposta per me è leggermente insoddisfacente perché, anche se sappiamo tutti che la regola è questa, la parte interessante è capire come la regola si sia originata e perché sia diversa dalle regole per le altre lingue neolatine.

Comment: @Denis Nardin, la domanda era: "Esiste proprio una ragione grammaticale dietro questa frase o è solo un modo di dire?". La risposta alla domanda è: SI, è una regola grammaticale: con i numerali "tutto" è seguito dalla congiunzione "e". Io ho dato una risposta precisa esattamente alla richiesta fatta, e in ogni caso uscire "fuori tema" mi avrebbe fatto certamente downvotare. Mi dispiace solo che qualcuno lo abbia fatto ugualmente e purtroppo ingiustamente.

Comment: Non prenderla come un'offesa personale. Puoi comunque migliorare la tua risposta includendo il riferimento che hai messo nei commenti alla grammatica Treccani (o ad una qualsiasi altra grammatica: sospetto che l'uso frequente della Treccani sia dovuto al fatto che è facilmente disponibile online), magari questo ti può aiutare a ricevere più voti positivi

Comment: @Denis Nardin, grazie, non la prendo assolutamente come offesa personale, volevo solo rispondere a una domanda e la risposta che ho dato è di una precisione chirurgica.
Inoltre onestamente non saprei spiegare come la regola si sia originata, non sono certo un'enciclopedia, ma amo moltissimo la mia lingua, che ho studiato a fondo al liceo classico, assieme al latino e al greco antico. Non sono offesa, sono stupita, perché “downvotare” risposte esatte non rientra nel Codice di Condotta di SE. Non morirò per questo! Grazie comunque, sei stato gentile, io upvoterò la tua risposta : )